# Perfect complexes on affine schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a paper on algebraic stacks and in some part is stated the following:

Let $X$ be an algebraic stack and let 
$P\in D_{qc}(X)$ be a perfect complex. Then, for every $x\in |X|$, there exists a flat morphism of locally of finite presentation $f: \mbox{Spec}(A)\rightarrow X$ with image
containing $x$ such that $R\Gamma(\mbox{Spec}(A), Lf^
∗_{qc}P)$ is a strictly perfect complex of
$A$-modules. In particular, every perfect complex on an affine scheme is strictly perfect.

My question is: How is deduced from this that every perfect complex on an affine scheme is strictly perfect?

Comment: No, it is *used*. A perfect complex on an affine scheme is strictly perfect: just take a projective resolution. It is easy to see that it may be taken bounded so "is" strictly perfect **in the derived category**.